# nginxでERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: go, nginx

nginxを使ってgoで書かれたWebサーバにリバースプロキシしていますが、タイトルのエラーでページが表示されません。

**default.conf**

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        #root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        #index  index.html index.htm;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:60000/;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

**goのメイン関数**

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/labstack/echo"
    mw "github.com/labstack/echo/middleware"
    "github.com/thoas/stats"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    e := echo.New()

    // Middleware.
    e.Use(mw.Logger())
    e.Use(mw.Recover())
    e.Use(mw.Gzip())
    s := stats.New()
    e.Use(s.Handler)

    // Index page.
    e.Index("public/")

    // Static files.
    e.Static("/js", "public/js")
    e.Static("/css", "public/css")
    e.Static("/images", "public/images")

    if port := os.Getenv("PORT"); port != "" {
        e.Run(":" + port)
    } else {
        e.Run(":3000")
    }
}
```

このGoのWebサーバプログラムは`/var/www/html/[page-name]`以下に存在します。

ローカルで確認しましたがちゃんと表示されました。
アクセスしてみると

```
INFO|echo|127.0.0.1 GET / 200 51.487429ms 13820
INFO|echo|127.0.0.1 GET / 200 9.556293ms 13820
INFO|echo|127.0.0.1 GET / 200 8.84661ms 13820
```

このようにコンソールに表示されますが、ページが表示されません。なぜ表示されないのでしょうか。

**nginx.conf**

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

追記 error_log

```
2016/02/11 04:32:39 [notice] 29316#0: signal process started
2016/02/11 04:32:45 [alert] 23756#0: worker process 29319 exited on signal 11
2016/02/11 04:32:46 [alert] 23756#0: worker process 29324 exited on signal 11
2016/02/11 07:09:02 [error] 29320#0: *241 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.10.100, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:60000/", host: "192.168.10.105"
```

一部ですが上記にようなものがたくさん書かれていました。

サーバ側での80番ポートtcpdump結果

```
01:02:40.058334 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 33406, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 471)
    192.168.10.100.56136 > 192.168.10.105.http: Flags [P.], cksum 0x9494 (correct), seq 1:420, ack 1, win 4117, options [nop,nop,TS val 300422591 ecr 15850679], length 419
E....~@.@. ...
d..
i.H.P..Y....X...........
........GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.10.105
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: ja,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
```

Comment: 設定されています。

Comment: `192.168.10.100 - - [11/Feb/2016:07:09:02 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 537 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36" "-"` Nginxのログです。

Comment: すみません。間違えました。長っかたので本文に追記しました。

Comment: `tcp6       0      0 :::60000                :::*                    LISTEN`このように表示されました。

Comment: `Ubuntu 16.04, nginx 1.9.10, go devel +cc0a04d Fri Feb 12` の環境で上記のプログラムと設定を試してみましたが、`public/index.html` の内容が正常に表示されました。違いがあるとすれば golang の HTTP サーバプログラムを `Document root` 以下に置いていない、という点でしょうか。

Comment: @argus それはnginxのdefault.conf, location内のrootをサーバプログラムの場所である`/var/www/html/[project-name]`に変更すればいいのでしょうか。であるなら、うまくできませんでした。もしよろしければnginxの設定ファイルの相似点をお教えいただけないでしょうか。また、(Go言語で書かれた方の)プログラムのログはでているので、nginx→GoWebサーバへの転送は成功していて、GoWebサーバ→nginxまたはnginx→クライアントへの帰りのパケットがうまく送信されていないのではないかと考えています。

Comment: proxyがWebサーバに接続できているなら僕の回答は意味がないので消しました。質問文からはそうは読み取れなかったので。

Comment: nginx.conf の違いは、`user www-data;`, `worker_processes auto;`, `tcp_nopush on;`, `gzip on;` になります。

Answer (score 1):

手前味噌で恐縮ですが、自分はこんな感じの実装で動きました。
ローカル（というかVM上）もリモート環境も確認済みです。

https://github.com/syo-sa1982/GoNTAkun/blob/master/main.go

因みにnginxの設定は
default.confのみ質問者さんと同じ内容で、それ以外は特に触って居ません。

参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。参考にさせていただきます。